# Puzzled about downvotes on this question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

I'm wondering about the downvotes on this question - [what is procedure to become a cricket umpire in state level?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7231/what-is-procedure-to-become-a-cricket-umpire-in-state-level)

It was written in poor English, but this was tidied up by myself & another user. It's on-topic, asks for specific information and is answerable. Any idea why people are downvoting it?

Comment: If I had a guess, it would be because of "localization," but based on [this past meta discussion](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/278/range-of-localization-for-sports-questions) as well as [this one](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/470/location-specific-questions-allowed?lq=1), localization is acceptable here.

Comment: [The same question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2611/540) was asked before. And it got [a very good and detailed answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/2614/540).

Comment: @hims056 Why not close as a duplicate (and not too broad) if that is the case? Also, is state/international procedures very similar to the point that it renders the question a duplicate? I know you can only speak for yourself, but I wonder why this would have been relatively ignored...

Comment: @edmastermind29 - Actually, I didn't close it. When I show the second question, it was already closed. I just referred them the older one. Also, being an international level umpire covers the procedures of state level umpire. You may open it again then close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @hims056 Point taken. Thanks. This question has been closed as a duplicate.